# IP address and subnetmask

Tags: ip

I have been given a Host A with an IP Adress of 192.168.100.100 and a Subnet Mask of 255.255.255.240.
Also, there are 7 pc configured with ip adresses and subnet masks written below. The question is, if the Host A and all of 7 PC are
linked on a single switch, which PC are ought to be communicating with the Host A.

A. 192.168.100.200/28
B. 192.168.100.99/28
C. 192.168.100.111/28
D. 192.168.100.97/28
E. 192.168.100.112/28
F. 192.168.100.95/28
G. 192.168.100.92/28

I would appreciate an insighted solution of the question

Answer (score 1):

Convert each address to a cdir:

```
 $ for spec in 192.168.100.100/255.255.255.240 192.168.100.200/28 192.168.100.99/28 192.168.100.111/28 192.168.100.97/28 192.168.100.112/28 192.168.100.92/28; do netmask -c $spec; done
  192.168.100.96/28
 192.168.100.192/28
  192.168.100.96/28
  192.168.100.96/28
  192.168.100.96/28
 192.168.100.112/28
  192.168.100.80/28
```

Then on your test write down B, C, D.